# How to give space between two blocks in drupal 7?

Tags: theming

How to give space in between two blocks in a responsive single page website in drupal 7? Example: we created two blocks about us and ethics in one row through drupal admin .We want to give vertical space between these two blocks!!

Comment: Each block has a unique identifier that you can *target* using CSS selectors. Just add some margin-bottom or something. No Drupal configuration is necessary.

Comment: Hi, we can't help you with your CSS here I'm afraid, this site is for questions about Drupal only.